# FB.getLoginStatus is not firing even the sandbox settings are off

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook API in order to check if the user who visits my page is logged into Facebook or not. I tried everything, couldn't came up with a solution. I would like to especially state that **sandbox mode is off**. And my code is right below;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>

    function fbLoginStatus(response) {
        console.log("Status: "+response.session);
         if(response.session) {
            //user is logged in, display profile div
            alert("Logged in");
         } else {
            //user is not logged in, display guest div
            alert("Not logged in");
         }
     }
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '111111111111111',  // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            console.log("Hey");
            if(response.session){
                console.log("You are logged in");
            }
            else{
                console.log("You are not logged in");
            }
        });
        // Additional initialization code here
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.getLoginStatus is the function that is used to detect if user is logged into FB or not. In the callback of function you are checking **response.session** but as per my understanding this **session** is not a valid attribute of returning JSON object. You should use **response.status**. So code will become like below.

```
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert("LOG IN");
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Hope this Helps

Kaushik